Do multiple requests being sent at once slow each individual request down?
So I am working in a program that sends multiple (around 100) requests per second, each to a different website. The requests are sent asynchronously in around 10 different threads, so they aren't blocking each other during execution. My question is if I were to send an extra request (in addition to those 100 requests) in a new thread, would it be slower or equal in speed to the same request being made alone (without the other 100 requests being sent)?
I am coding in Python and using the requests module. My current code already does the 100 requests and that additional request once every minute or so.

Yes and no. There is a part of the operation which is done serially in only one thread so this part increase with the number of request. Probing the state of the request can also be a bit slower per request with more request. However, most of the time is generally spent waiting for the request to be received (latency). Another limitation is the throughput which is limited by your connection and your NIC (as well as the network of your FAI and CSPs though they should not to be a bottleneck). Many request are more likely to saturate this bandwidth.

You need to profile so to know. If the first thread is still latency-bound and the bandwidth of networks is not saturated, then using another thread should not help much. Otherwise, it can help assuming the bandwidth is not a problem. If the bandwidth is saturated, there is nothing to do (besides enabling compression). Note that multithreading in Python is limited by the GIL so it only help to reduce latency. There is no real parallelism in most cases (unless the GIL is released which I expect not to be the case). Put it shortly: threads should not help much compared to async.
